# Android app crashes, setting textview to number

Tags: java, android

Relative new to Android and Java programming. I have one TextView with the number 0 in, which will show the number as it get bigger or smaller. I also have two buttons, one to add, one to subtract, both call their own method, the ones below. When I launch this app, it crashes.

```
TextView numberView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
int number = 0;

public void addNumber(View view) {
    number++;
    numberView.setText(number);
}

public void subtractNumber(View view) {
    number--;
    numberView.setText(number);
}
```

I also tried 
        numberView.setText(Integer.toString(number));

Comment: It's been asked a million times. Move `numberView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);` to `onCreate` after `setContentView`. Keep the declaration out of the method. The answers will solve your next problem.

Comment: post the stacktrace of the error

Comment: Thanks a lot @EugenPechanec ! Saved me from a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't a null pointer exception
Then you can do this `numberView.setText(number+"")`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
numberView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```

Comment: It still crashes on startup.

Comment: post your logcat please